# Databases: performance of dynamic vs. static lookups of the latest sample(s) in a table

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb

I have a table that collects samples for the temperature in different cities, which are distinguished by a city-id. Every sample is saved along with a timestamp.

```
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | city_id | temperature | fetched             |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |          10 | 2016-01-28 00:50:27 |
|  2 |       1 |          12 | 2016-01-27 23:51:45 |
|  3 |       2 |          22 | 2016-01-27 23:52:05 |
|  4 |       2 |          25 | 2016-01-28 00:52:25 |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

If i want to get the latest temperatures for all cities, i can use a self-join [1]:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM sample s 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT city_id, MAX(fetched) maxFetched
    FROM sample
    GROUP BY city_id
) j 
ON s.city_id = j.city_id AND s.fetched = j.maxFetched;

+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | city_id | temperature | fetched             |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |          10 | 2016-01-28 00:50:27 |
|  4 |       2 |          25 | 2016-01-28 00:52:25 |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Now, i was wondering about the performance when my table grows. Imagine i collect 1 sample per city per hour, so for e.g. 10 cities, after one year, the table will contain 10*24*365=87600 samples. Will the runtime of the MAX-function increase linearly with the input size? I.e. would it be better practice to have another table, e.g. last_sample, which saves a pointer to the latest sample, so that lookups for the latest temperatures per city only take constant time (maybe automatically updated when a new sample is added)? The same question applies when the query is abstracted in a view.

```
SELECT * FROM last_sample;
+------+---------+-----------+
| id   | city_id | sample_id |
+------+---------+-----------+
|    1 |       1 |         1 |
|    2 |       2 |         4 |
+------+---------+-----------+
```

Thanks!

[1] [MySQL get set of data with distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381859/mysql-get-set-of-data-with-distinct-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an example of the "groupwise max" problem.  Your code is "not too bad".  There are examples [*in here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) of faster ways to do it and scale.  And it discusses what to do if you do/don't want multiple rows when there are multiple rows with the same Max.

For your code, be sure to have this composite index:

```
INDEX(city_id, fetched)
```

Your subquery will use the index only.  (The `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` will show "Using index".) and, I think, leapfrog through the index finding the "city, max(fetched)" pairs very efficiently.

Then your `JOIN` will reach back into the table using that same index.

Even better would be to get rid of `id` (does it really serve any purpose) since `(city_id, fetched)` is "unique" (Yes?) and, therefore, could be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  In that case, the `INDEX` I suggested would not be needed.  And all the secondary probes would be very efficient (because of using the PK).

Bottom line:

- Toss `id`
- Change to `PRIMARY KEY(city_id, fetched)
- (You won't find anything better in my blog.)
- It will grow linearly (and so will the output)

But... If you decide to limit it to `fetched BETWEEN ... AND ...`, all bets are off.  (I would need to rethink things.)

Comment: Thanks Rick! For this example, i could remove `id`, `(city_id, fetched)` is unique here.  But would that be a good idea if i had linked to a sample from another table (e.g. `other.sample_id -> sample.id` as foreign key)? And how would i query the table, when i have no idea how the timestamps look like?